# Combine multiple CSV files using Python and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
allFiles = glob.glob("C:\*.csv")
frame = pd.DataFrame()
list_ = []
for file_ in allFiles:
    print file_
    df = pd.read_csv(file_,index_col=None, header=0)
    list_.append(df)
    frame = pd.concat(list_, sort=False)
print list_
frame.to_csv("C:\f.csv")
```

This combines multiple CSVs to single CSV.

However it also adds a row number column.

Input:

a.csv

```
a   b   c   d
1   2   3   4
```

b.csv

```
a   b   c   d
551 55  55  55
551 55  55  55
```

result:
f.csv

```
    a   b   c   d
0   1   2   3   4
0   551 55  55  55
1   551 55  55  55
```

How can I modify the code not to show the row numbers in the output file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use pandas for this simple task. pandas is parsing the file and converting the data to numpy constructs, which you don't need... In fact you can do it with just normal text file manipulation:

```
import glob
allFiles = glob.glob("C:\*.csv")
first = True
with open('C:\f.csv', 'w') as fw:
    for filename in allFiles:
        print filename
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            if not first:
                f.readline() # skip header
            first = False
            fw.writelines(f)
```

Comment: This code also adds the header from each file. The header should be shown only once. The fw.writelines(f) needs to be conditional - write the row only if it's no the header row except the first time.

Comment: I fixed it with a flag @jack

Answer (score 2):

Change `frame.to_csv("C:\f.csv")` to `frame.to_csv("C:\f.csv", index=False)`

See: [pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)